# rspec-rails gem exec after dispaly error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have create a static_pages_controller.rb

which i have create one function

```
def home


end
```

after that i have create a view home.html.erb
which i have just write done this "Sample App"

After that i have install gem rspec-rails and create static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "StaticPages" do
    describe "Home page" do
        it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
            visit '/static_pages/home'
            page.should have content('Sample App')
        end
    end
end
```

i have run this command on terminal

```
$  bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) StaticPages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa3a7870>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00248 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:4 # StaticPages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'

Randomized with seed 57243
```

what it is wrong ? with this please hellp me

Answer (score 1):

`visit` is part of the Capybara DSL.  Whilst it used to be loaded automatically for tests in `spec/requests`, that was changed [in this commit](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/de34c638354c117f20269b4fd129c2657b01ef12) to load automatically for tests in `spec/features` instead.

You can either move your spec to `spec/features` and it should work, or you have to explicitly include `Capybara::DSL` in your `spec_helper.rb` if you want to leave the spec where it is.

This is assuming you have Capybara installed and required.

In you `Gemfile` you should have:

```
gem 'capybara'
```

And in your `spec_helper.rb` you should have:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Comment: Rename `spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` to be `spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb` (i.e. put it in a features subdirectory instead of requests) and it should work.

Comment: Now my directory stu like this "spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb" and i run this command "$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb" not working

Comment: Do you have Capybara installed?  I've edited my answer.